# Effects of debugger on embedded application

Tags: c, debugging, embedded, stm32, iar

I'm currently using IAR to debug an STM32f0 micro, and I've noticed some interesting effects on my device's functionality while attempting to debug when the unit is running.

It seems to me that the debugger is slowing down or inhibiting the application in some way, meaning some of the more time critical sections of the code are having trouble executing correctly.

What is the debugger doing to the code in order to allow me to look at the registers/variables/memory/position in source code, and how does this affect execution time?

Note: optimisations are already turned off, as they tend to stuff up IAR's ability to step through code correctly and cause it to sometimes miss breakpoints.

Comment: That likely depends on the debugger and if/how many variables you monitor while the prorgam runs, your code, etc. About optimisations: Use a toolchain which can handle that smarter and does not cost more than your PC: gcc.

Comment: Hi Olaf, thanks for your reply. I've always assumed that the variables you monitor/registers you view are only updated when a breakpoint is hit, and their status is not constantly transmitted to the PC - so how would this effect the application code? The comment on gcc is helpful, and we use gcc regularly for another project, so may pay to make the switch. Cheers, Sean.

Comment: I moved away from IAR for my own projects long time ago. The only thing I regretted was I did not earlier. Every time I have to use it in my job, it reminds me how good it was moving. Anyway, I can't tell you how IAR works exactly and I don't know your setup. It might even relate to your JTAG/SWD interface or other mechanisms. I certainly can&will not assure you won't have the same problem with gdb/openocd.

Comment: so if you use the same exact binary, with the debugger it is slower than without?  Or do you have to things changing at once?  compile for debug and use the debugger, vs compile differently and not use the debugger?

Comment: Identical binary but when running the code from IAR we encounter the issues. We're making use of the low level peripherals and STM's FOC library to do some motor control, so the timing needs to very accurate which makes me think there must be some delays inherited when running the debugger.

Comment: There's also the very basics: your MCU will have just so many hardware breakpoints. If you use more breakpoints than there are hardware breakpoints available, the debugger will attempt some manner of software breakpoints and your program will become slower. No tool chain in the world will save you from that.

Comment: Software breakpoints aren't any slower than hardware breakpoints unless they're conditional breakpoints.   A software breakpoint is just replacing the normal instruction with the BKPT instruction, causing the debugger to halt when it tries to execute that instruction.  If it's conditional, then it will halt the cpu, notify the debugger, have teh debugger query variables, etc and determine if it should stop or not, and continue if it's not supposed to halt.  This makes microseconds of execution time turn into (tens of) milliseconds.

Comment: @RussSchultz: You hardly can replace the data in a single Flash cell without erasing the whole sector. Think how many cycles that means for a bit more complex stepping through a simple program. The Flash will pretty soon be worn out. Not to mention the time to erase/program.

Comment: We're not using any software breakpoints (apart from one in the hardfault handler as there's nothing implemented here yet) so this shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @Olaf  I'm actually used to debugging stuff that's loaded into RAM (and not executed directly from directly mapped flash), so software breakpoints are as I describe..  In any case, single stepping is usually implemented by using one of the hardware breakpoints, or by feeding the MCU directly (if you're instruction stepping).

Comment: @RussSchultz: I commented on your statement "A software breakpoint is just replacing the normal instruction with the BKPT instruction". On a CM0 and most other Cortex-M MCUs running code from Flash is the far by most common case. And for single stepping, there are additional mechanisms. All this costs massive time because of the JTAG/SWD interface communication required. And that heavily depends on the internal "intelligence" of the interface and the (typically) USB communication with the PC required.

Comment: @olaf  "software breakpoints" really don't exist on execute for flash, for the reasons you suggest.  If they do exist, they require you to update the flash, then there's STILL no impact on running except when you're setting them.   Single stepping is irrelevant because you're single stepping and impacting the system by stopping it every line (or instruction).   Generally, the only impact a JTAG debugger has is if there's an exception that's being trapped (e.g. for printf() or file IO), or conditional breakpoints

Comment: @RussSchultz: Software breakpoints very well exist in Flash, too. I e.g. use `BKPT` in assertions. That way during debugging it stops at the place the assertion occurs, not some nested function. And at run-time I can catch&handle the exception. It is just useless to have a debugger use them dynamically (I think I described the procedure in my earlier post already). And no, the interface very well has impact, as you have to update the breakpoint registers after every step. Of course, that does not have _much_ impact for _manual_ single-stepping, but how about auto-stepping, e.g. for tracing?

Answer (score 2):

The ARM Cortex-M0 CoreSight on-chip debug unit used of the STM32F0xx is non-intrusive for normal execution.  Hardware breakpoints matched instruction-fetch addresses in real-time.  If your debugger supports update of memory content and variables while running (rather then at a breakpoint), that may conceivably have an effect, but on STM32F2xx with I have not seen any issues even with very time critical code with with microsecond scale deadlines (F2 is however Cortex-M3 not M0).

Applying conditional breakpoints will slow execution considerably, if the breakpoint location is executed frequently since the processor must be stopped and the condition tested by the host.

A common problem encountered when debugging that may catch the unwary is that when the processor stops on a break-point, the on-chop peripherals and timers continue to run, of then resulting in several interrupts pending when the processor is restarted often with undesirable effects depending on your applications ability to handle such abnormal timing gracefully.  The DBGMCU peripheral supports the ability to selectively stop specific timers and peripherals, and to support low-power modes without disconnecting the debugger.  You may need to use these features to improve your debug experience.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Clifford, this is more the level of insight I was after. I've been doing some investigation into the ARM Cortex architecture and agree that there shouldn't be an issue. 

The DBGMCU peripheral you mention is currently setup when in debug mode for all timers in use. I was thinking it could also be a noise issue, which is highlighted only when the SWD/CLK pins have wires connected to them (possibly acting as an antenna?). 

Also it's worth noting there are no conditional breakpoints in the code, and only about four variables in the watch window.

Comment: @champagnedaddy: It may then pay you to add more information to the question. Currently it is qualitative rather than quantative; some actual comparative timing would help evidence that your problem is real, and to what extent. Include information on your method.  Also be sure that none of the debug pins are being reassigned alternate functions, or being accessed as GPIO.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the debugger doing to the code in order to allow me to look at
>   the registers/variables/memory/position in source code, and how does
>   this affect execution time?

It depends on your debugger. In general, debuggers slow the application (application performance) whether it is run in emulator or on the device itself based on the level of intrusiveness.

The breakpoints, single stepping can have huge impact on the timing of execution of application as they are intrusive. Also note that the intrusiveness due to these features in turn depends on the offering by the vendor.

Normally, debuggers shall read the CPU registers and memory so that it can be displayed to the user, however this process shall consume memory/time in turn causing side effect.

Some debug techniques used by debuggers involve incorporation of additional information into the application code which in turn can increase the size of application which can effect the execution time. Such intrusive techniques can cause side effects due to this additional code.

Comment: The question is very specifically about STM32F0 which has on-chip debug hardware, this answer is more general and some of the points do not apply.  Moreover debug information generated by the compiler/linker is not included in the executable code and does not impact performance; it is used by the host debugger only to associate specific addresses with variables and lines of code.